# Changing Range("blah").Value in a row loop

Tags: excel, vba

In VBA, if your looping through a range, lets call it "Times" by doing

```
 For Each row In Times.Rows

      code in here...

 Next row
```

And you want your code to take in Range("blah").Value which corresponds to a specific cell in a row. What do you put in for "blah" so that it will change corresponding to what row your are in?

In other words... 
  Say for instance, the first row is in your Times range is 2 and you want "A2" then you would write Range("A2").Value, but what if I want it to "change" to Range("B2").Value when you move onto the next row in my loop? Is there something in VBA that allows you to do this?

Comment: If there's no pattern you would have to define it using If statements. If you're always moving across and down one it would be simpler.

Comment: I've read your question several times and I'm still not sure I understand the desired relation between rows in `Times` and the other cells.

Comment: Your Question is not clear. Please redefine your questions

Comment: Use `.Cells(row, column)` instead of `.Range("A1")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
For Each row In Times.Rows

      Range("A" & row) = "Blah"

 Next row
```

or

```
For Each row In Times.Rows

      Cells(row, 1) = "Blah"

 Next row
```

If you column never changes, I'd use the first example with Range. If your column changes too, it's easier to use the Cells method because it references by a number rather than a letter and thus can be a variable as well.

Comment: `Cells(row, 1)` means `Cells(row.Value, 1)`, which takes the column number from the cell value as opposed to the cell's row, and it will fail if `Times` contains multiple columns.